# Los valores de SE

Tags: pronombres

Encontré unas preguntas cuando estuve haciendo los ejercicios sobre los valores de SE. ¿Podrían ayudarme?

1. SE le trató muy bien. (Creí que es Verbo Pronominal por tratarse, pero la correcta es, ¿"Marca de impersonal"? ¿Por qué? Doesn´t it mean "He treated him very well?")
2. En este país no SE toma en serio la cultura. (Creí que es "Marca de impersonal", pero la correcta es "Marca de pasiva". Doesn´t it mean "People don´t take culture in serious in this country?)
3. SE colocaron todos en fila. (Creí que es "Marca de pasiva", pero la correcta es "Verbo pronominal". Doesn´t it mean "All is put in line"?)
4. Tu amigo SE cree muy listo. (Creí que es "Verbo pronominal" por creerse, pero la correcta es "Reflexivo Complemento Directo". Doesn´t it mean "Your friend thinks himself being very clever".)
5. Por fin, SE durmió. (Creí que es "Reflexivo Complemento Directo" por dormirse, pero la correcta es "Verbo pronominal". Doesn´t it mean "Finally, he slept.")

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I see it this way:

1, **SE le trató muy bien.** = They treated him very well
Aqui, no es una persona especifica que le trata bien. Es 'la gente'. Algo desconocido.
"¿Cómo estuvo su viaje?" "Se me trató muy bien." 
"Él se le trató bien" does not exist!
*--> Marca impersonal*

2, **En este país no SE toma en serio la cultura.** = In this country they do not take culture seriously
Ahí no estoy muy segura:
Se puede decir: "la cultura no está tomada en serio". Tomar en serio la cultura es lo importante, no el sujeto
*--> Marca pasiva*
Aúnque no veo porque no puede ser marca impersonal
*--> Marca impersonal??*

3, **SE colocaron todos en fila.** = They get in line/ They put themselves in line
En esta situación ya se sabe de quien están hablando, p.ej. de los alumnos... sólo que no se repite el sujeto.
Son estos mismos alumnos que se colocan, asi que no es pasivo.
Viene de colocarse, lo que no se hace realmente a sí mismo es un movimiento.
*--> Verbo pronominal* 
Ahí no se puede formar una oración pasiva.

4, **Tu amigo SE cree muy listo.** = Your friend thinks himself to be very clever
 
Se cree a sí mismo (himself), sí mismo es siempre reflexivo.
Who he thinks is very clever, himself. so the himself must be direct object.
*--> Reflexivo y Complemento Directo*

5, **Por fin, SE durmió.** Finally, he/she fell asleep.
Igual a frase 3, estan por ejemplo hablando del niño, y por fin, 'el niño se durmió'. Sin repetir sujeto por supuesto.
Viene de dormirse (entrar a dormir), dormir significa otra cosa, es ya estar durmiendo.
*--> Verbo pronominal*
No se duerme a sí mismo, asique no puede ser reflexivo.

Comment: @Silke : for " se colocaron todas end fila", if the implied subject are , for example, sillas, then we can say "the sillas are lined up". This is a passive voice, no?

Comment: @Cadenza I would say that if it concerns chairs, you can say: `Se las colocaron todas en fila`. But then your subject is impersonal. Someone put them on a line.<br/> `Se colocaron todas en fila` would mean that the chairs put themselves in line. Which would then be reflexivo

Comment: @Silke: Couldn't we say it this way. If the chairs are mentioned earlier, and now when we say "se colocaron todas end fila" , we can see it as the chairs are lined up by someone which is passive voice. No?

Comment: @Cadenza: `están colocadas en fila`, `ellos las colocaron en fila`, `se las colocaron en fila`.. No sé, tal vez me equivoque y si se puede usar también. A mí, personalmente, me suena extraño.

Comment: @Silke in the context of point #1, does it work with "se hace falta"?

Comment: @Sebas: To my opinion, yes :)

Comment: @Sebas: I have to correct myself I think. After seeing you [question](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/3627/me-te-nos-hace-falta-passive-form/3628#3628), I did some research after the "se hace falta", which I also frequently use, and noticed there is an important grammatical difference with point #1 of this question.