# What is the history of the "personal a"?

Tags: historia, preposiciones, a-personal

What is the historical origin of the "[personal *a*](http://www.studyspanish.com/lessons/persa.htm)" in Spanish?

Examples of the *personal a*:

> George sees Mary. -> *Jorge ve **a** María.*
>   I see the waitress. -> *Veo **a** la mesera.*

But with the exact same sentence structure, the 'a' is omitted when referencing non-persons:

> George sees the dog. -> *Jorge ve el perro.*
>   I see the table. -> *Veo la mesa.*

Answer (score 6):

The personal a can be confusing to English speakers because we are accustomed to **sentence structure conveying meaning**.

For example, when I say

> John picked up the brother

it's "obvious" that the brother is the direct object. We take it for granted in English but the reason we know this is because brother *comes after the verb*. Reversing it:

> The brother picked up John

changes the meaning of the sentence. Specifically, who is the direct object and who is the subject.

In Spanish that same meaning is **not** conveyed by sentence structure. For example:

> Jorge **ve** María -> ??
>
> María **ve** Jorge. -> ??

We have no idea who saw who. While to English natives it appears we can understand the sentences, in reality the meaning is not there.

This is where the personal a comes in.

> Jorge ve **a María** -> George sees Mary.
>
> **A Jorge** ve María. -> Mary sees George.

Now we can tell who sees who. The personal a indicates who is the direct object.

The personal a is mostly used when the direct object is a person, but it can also be applied to things that can be personified, e.g. pets.

> Juanita extraña a su perro.

Another example is with certain pronouns, e.g. alguien, nadie, quien, etc.

> Yo no vi **a nadie**
>
> A quien pertenece la tele?

The benefit of all this is that Spanish gives the speaker much more flexibility in constructing sentences. This is common throughout the language, e.g.:

> Me quiero ir

vs

> Quiero irme

Both mean "I want to leave"

Comment: It makes sense to use the 'a' to avoid ambiguity, but it's used even when it's completely unambiguous, such as *Veo a María* (without the *a* it still could not be construed as María sees me). It would also seem that this rule would apply to inanimate objects. *El árbol aplastó el coche.* If the rule was about avoiding ambiguity, shouldn't this be *El árbol aplastó **al** coche.*?

Comment: Very good points. Perhaps I should have added that these are general rules and do not apply in all cases.

Comment: En "Jorge ve María" está muy claro que quien ve algo es Jorge, lo que no queda claro es qué es lo que ve. No puede ser una mujer (Jorge ve a María), ni algo específico, como una carabela de Cristobal Colón (Jorge ve a la (Santa) María), así que la primera interpretación sería que Jorque está drogado y ve maría (marihuana) en sus alucinaciones.

Comment: @TrevorMcKendrick: There are enough exceptions, that it seems the ambiguity "rule" isn't the actual reason for the *personal a*; unless you have some reference showing this to actually be the case.

Comment: I think you have to understand the ambiguity rule as an explanation of how the speech pattern came about, and not as a rule that the native speaker is applying in his head wenever he speaks.

Comment: Esta cuestión de ambigüedad depende del contexto.  Yo no sé si se dice "Juan ve el computador" o "Juan ve al computador".  Lo que sí voy a decir es que la idea de un computador con cámara de television era casi desconocida, años atras.  Hoy es común.

Answer (score 4):

Habrá que remontarse al latín, porque en el español antiguo ya estaba:

> *Enbió el rey don Alfonso **a** Ruy Díaz mio Çid por las parias que le avían a dar los reyes de Córdova e de Sevilla cada año.*

Según la RAE procede del latín *ad* (*to*, *toward*, en inglés), que es una preposición de acusativo que indica dirección (hacia, hasta,etc...), proximidad (junto a, en,...), finalidad (para,...)  o comparación (ante,según, ...) y que en todos esos significados puede traducirse a veces como "a" en español. La palabra latina procede del  protoindoeuropeo y está relacionado con el *at* del inglés (de origen protogermámico).

Esa indicación de orientación, como explica Trevor, en los complementos directos (CD) personificados evita la ambigüedad del español, donde no es obligatoria la presencia del sujeto delante del verbo, a diferencia de otros idiomas. De esta forma

> Jorge quiere María (ambiguo)

Podría interpretarse como:

> Jorge quiere a María (no ambiguo)

Pero también podría ser:

> A Jorge quiere María  (no ambiguo)

Pero también esa orientación ejerce una restricción semántica de *especificidad* y definición, que puede ser aplicable **o no* a personas u objetos más o menos personificados:

> Conozco a un policía (persona específica: Pepe)
>
> Necesito un policía (persona no específicada: Pepe, Juan, etc.)

Si en vez de policía ponemos un nombre propio (Pepe), el CD es necesariamente específico, y por tanto con "a".

En caso de CD que son cosas comunes, como "una pared", ciertamente puede omitirse la "a" porque no son única

> Pintó la mesa

Pero la razón no es simplemente que el CD no sea personal. También ocurre que no hay un sentido de dirección o movimiento, ni es ambiguo. De tal forma sí se emplea en:

> Saltó a la mesa  (alguien salta sobre la mesa)

Y si se quita:

> Saltó la mesa (*Poltergesist phenomenon*)

Comment: If I understand, this explains the origin of **a**, but not specifically its use before a name or reference to a specific person.

Comment: @Flimzy. No comprendo que no comprendes. Simplemente seguimos usando el "ad" del latín que tenía un uso muy diverso, para un uso igualmente diverso, pero en buena parte el mismo, incluyendo incluyendo el complemento directo si es una persona. Siguiendo el ejemplo del enlace (que por cierto, tiene algún error), un hispanohablante no piensa  "George calls Mary" sino que "Goerge calls to Mary", porque "Goerge calls in the direction of Mary", empleando el _to_ exactamente con el mismo significado del _ad_ en latín que seguimos usando como _a_ ¿qué queda entonces por explicar?

Comment: En el contexto de "Goeroge calls to Mary", el *a* es común en muchos idiomas, incluso inglés. Pero en otros contextos, el *a personal* se requiere en español pero no en otros idioms, ni en español con otros objetos. Ejemplo: "George sees Mary" -> "Jorge ve a Maria" vs. "Goerge sees the house" -> "Jorge ve la casa." (no "a la casa").

Comment: Sí, pero fíjate que depende mucho que el significado del verbo encaje con el "ad" latino (dirección, tendencia, etc.) y no tanto del objeto. Es cierto que "Jorge ve a María" mientras "Jorge ve la casa" o "Jorge le gusta la casa" pero "Jorge va *a* (hacia) la casa" y "Jorge disparó *a* (contra) la casa". En cambio a "Jorge le gusta María" (sin a, porque el gusto es reflexivo, no se dirige a María) y en cambio "Jorge busca a María".

Comment: En ese sentido, las personas o incluso las cosas llevan la preposición "a" para reforzar que la acción se direcciona hacia ellos. Así "buscamos la criada perfecta" no es lo mismo que "buscamos a la criada perfecta" porque el en primer caso puede ser cualquiera (buscamos sin dirección) y el segundo sabemos como se llama y la buscamos **en**,**hacia**,**hasta** ella (en su  dirección) y con un mnombre propio ocurre exactamente lo mismo.

Comment: @Fran "Jorge le gusta María" es sin "a" porque María no es el objeto directo aqui, es el sujeto. De todos modos no tiene el "a personal"

Comment: @Silke, no, no, no. En "A Jorge le gusta María" (sin la "a" inicial tampoco tendría sentido), Jorge es el sujeto: ¿a **quién** le gusta? A jorge. María es el objeto directo: ¿ **qué** le gusta? María.

Comment: @Fran, entiendo su lógica. Lo que usted dice es el **sujeto animado** (y cómo derivar el sujeto animado). Para entender el "a" personal, nos hace falta el **sujeto gramatical**. El sujeto gramatical es a cual esta liado la conjugación del verbo (le gusta María, le gustas tú..). Jorge es el objeto indirecto gramatical, lo que deja claro el "le" lo que es el doble objeto indirecto (a Jorge le gusta, a ellos les gusta...). Me hizo pensar en [la pregunta sobre "me hace falta"](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/3627/me-te-nos-hace-falta-passive-form), que se basa un poco en lo mismo.

Comment: Ahí encontré una investigación sobre la confusión respecto al sujeto: el [artículo](http://www.academia.edu/3358508/Problemas_en_el_reconocimiento_de_los_sujetos_logicos_y_gramaticales_en_los_verbos_psicologicos_una_mirada_lexico-sintactica) y la introdución de [esto](http://lib.ugent.be/fulltxt/RUG01/000/483/575/RUG01-000483575_2010_0001_AC.pdf) explica bien sobre los verbos psicológicos. (Disculpa que estoy saliendo de la pregunta original!)

Comment: I was curious about the latin ad and saw that for example: for **Jorge ve a María**, there is no "ad": I think it must be: **Jorges Mariam videt** or **Jorges videt Mariam**

Comment: @Silke, efectivamente me refería al sujeto lógico, que en el caso de "gustar" no es el gramatical, a menos que se use "gustar de". No fue un acierto usar ese verbo para los ejemplos.

Comment: @Silke, I really know very little Latin, but like translating to other languages, I suppose that often you cannot make literal translations. However, for example you can translate _Petere aliquid ad aliquem_ as _pedir algo a alguien_.

Comment: In "George sees Mary", Mary is a direct object.  In "Jorge ve a María", María is the object of a prepositional phrase.  The structure of the sentence is different in the two languages, even though they are translations of each other.