# "a" personal en "Yo les presento a mi novio a mis padres"?

Tags: gramática, preposiciones

Estaba viendo la [pregunta sobre el "a" personal](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/3719/what-is-the-history-of-the-personal-a) y empecé a estudiar un poco el asunto. Me quedé con la duda, qué pasa con la "a" personal en caso de que se agregue a un objeto indirecto.

Pensé en este ejemplo:

> "Yo les presento **a** mi novio a mis padres"

Es mi novio al que presento a mis padres, entonces "mi novio" es el objeto directo, y es una persona. Entonces se usa el "a" personal.
"mis padres" es el objeto indirecto, lo que generalmente también va con "a".

Ahora mi duda es que siempre he escuchado esto (y también suena más claro y lógico):

> "Yo les presento mi novio a mis padres"

¿Ocurre solamente en la lengua hablada que dejan la primera "a"? ¿O la "a" puede desaparecer cuando se agrega un objeto indirecto?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Según el DPD, en este caso puede omitirse la primera preposición "a", salvo que vaya antes de un nombre propio](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=a):

> **d)** Cuando el complemento directo de persona precedido de preposición
>   coincide en la oración con otro complemento que también la lleva (por
>   ejemplo, un complemento indirecto), puede omitirse la que antecede al
>   complemento directo, para evitar confusiones: *Presentó (a) su novio a
>   sus padres*. Pero si el complemento directo es un nombre propio, es
>   forzoso el uso de la preposición: *Presentó a Juan a sus padres*.

Comment: Hasta sale con (casi) el mismo ejemplo! Gracias por resolver mi duda!

Answer (score 0):

No entiendo muy bien las reglas gramáticales para este ejemplo pero efectivamente suena bastante raro la primera frase. Puede ser en parte por que el tiempo en el que esta expresada es inadecuado (se indica que estas realizando la acción de presentar tu novio a tus papás mientras le dices a un tercer sujeto lo que estas haciendo).

> "Les presentaré a mi novio a mis padres"  (padres conociendo novio)
>
> "Le presentaré a mi novio a mis padres" (novio conociendo padres)
>
> "Le presentaré mi novio a mis padres"
> "Les presentaré mis padres a mi novio"

Las frases anteriores suenan mucho mejor y se entienden más claramente.
En el caso de las dos últimas, el  "mi" que sigue al verbo hace que la frase tenga sentido aún sin el "a" ya que nos permite identificar facilmente quien será presentado a quien, sin embargo el "a" no puede siempre omitirse porque algunas frases perderían su sentido, especialmente aquellas frases donde no podemos identificar a un sujeto de otro (quien es el objeto directo y quién es el objeto indirecto) como:

> "Le presentaré a Maria Juan"
> "Le presentaré a Maria a Juan"

Me parece que es bastante específico este problema con el verbo que estas ejemplificando porque siempre se presenta "a" alguien.

Comment: Disculpa el ejemplo, hay otros posibles ejemplos solo que tienes que poder usar CD y CI con una persona. Por ejemplo: "Les llevo (a) mi bebe a mis padres", porque es "llevo a mi bebe".

Comment: Tienes razón, no lo había considerado asi. También en el nuevo ejemplo que pones creo que podrías sustituir u omitir el "a" por el "mi" (o un posesivo culaquiera) que denuevo te permite identificar el objeto directo del indirecto. Asi mismo si pusieras "Les llevo el bebe a mis padres" funciona la oración porque denuevo se retira el "a" pero el artículo "el" nos permite difenciar entre los objetos de la oración