# When should I put the letter "a" in front of a name?

Tags: gramática, preposiciones, nombres-propios, persona-gramatical, a-personal

So I am trying to decide between these 2 sentences:

> Anthony Solares es una persona que limpia muchas casas. Él tiene un ingreso predictible.

and

> **A** Anthony Solares es una persona que limpia muchas casas. Él tiene un ingreso predictible.

Which one is correct? If you could tell me when to use / not to use "A" in front of a name, please do so.

Comment: Just a comment, the usual word for "predictable" is *predecible*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That usage of the preposition "a" is sometimes called *[a personal](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/3719/24236)* (personal "a"). It is used before all **indirect objects**, and before **direct objects that refer to a person**. It is never used before the subject of a sentence.

For example:

- Dale el documento *a Juan* (*indirect object*).
- No veo *a Pablo* (*direct object that refers to a person*).
- No veo *la estrella* (*direct object that does not refer to a person, so no "a"*).
- *Anthony Solares* es una persona que limpia muchas casas. (*subject, so no "a"*).

The complete rules and all the edge cases are listed [in DPD](https://www.rae.es/dpd/a).

Comment: This answer is really helpful. It summed up all the confusion I had around this topic.